# Running Python Code in C++ Cmake can't find PyUnicode_FromString

Tags: python, c++, linux, cmake, clion

I am trying to run python code in c++

```
#include <python3.7/Python.h>
// PYTHON START
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *module_name = PyUnicode_FromString("plotter");
PyObject *module = PyImport_Import(module_name);
Py_DECREF(module_name);

if (module != nullptr) {
    PyObject *py_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "plot_data");

    //call the python and pass the data generated in C
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (py_function && PyCallable_Check(py_function)) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            PyObject *res = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(py_function, q);
        }
    }
}
```

I've never done this before but I don't think that is the issue because I can't build the code.
my error is:

```
/snap/clion/81/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/alex/Workspace/Clion/krpc/cmake-build-debug --target krpc -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable krpc
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/krpc.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/alex/Workspace/Clion/krpc/test.cpp:43: undefined reference to `PyUnicode_FromString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/krpc.dir/build.make:85: krpc] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/krpc.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/krpc.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: krpc] Error 2
```

my cmake file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(krpc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


link_libraries("-lkrpc -lprotobuf -lpthread")
find_package(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(krpc test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(krpc ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

EDIT: My cmake output looks like this:

```
/snap/clion/81/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/alex/Workspace/Clion/krpc
-- PYTHON_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/Workspace/Clion/krpc/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

I have looked at find_packages() in cmake and if I just have normal python it finds python2.7 but I want 3.7. I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the output of your CMake when it runs? Please add the output to your question post. Can you add `message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES: ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")` before your call to `target_link_libraries` to see if the Python libraries were found correctly?

Comment: I added it, it looks like it is still just finding libpython2.7, when I change pythonlibs to pythonlibs3 however it spits out errors saying it cannot find python3, I don't know cmake well enough to configure it though

Comment: Have you added the path to your Python3 libraries to the `PATH` environment variable? Consider removing the path to your Python 2 libraries from `PATH` also.

Comment: You could probably change your `find_package` call to `find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)` to tell CMake to look for Python 3 only, and to fail if it is not found.

Comment: Using find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED) throws errors. I’ll have to double check my PATH when I get back to my computer. The errors on the pythonlibs 3 are consistent when cmake being unable to find python3. I just don’t know how to make it see it. I’ll try the PATH but any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Your linker trying to find PyUnicode_FromString in libpython.so. It is Python2, it doesn't have PyUnicode_FromString (It have only non-unicode PyString_FromString).

CMakeLists.txt example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(krpc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


link_libraries("-lkrpc -lprotobuf -lpthread")

add_executable(krpc test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(krpc python3.7m)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed after changing the required cmake to version 3.7.2 and then cleaning the cache of the project.